# Issue with creating thousands of div in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We need to create minute and second measurement units(displayed as bar) for 24 hours in HTML dynamically. We are using div for each unit.
For displaying units in second we need to create 86400 divs(24 * 60 * 60) and this is resulting in hanging the browser and not being able to create so many divs.

We used jquery html() method to create div as well as jsp pages to create so many divs. But both resulted in same way, browser gets hanged.

Is there any way to create 86400 divs using javascript (or any other way to be used in HTML)?

Code used:

```
var i;

for(i=0;i<86400;i++)
{
    $('#innerDiv').append('<div class="unit">'+i+'sec</div>');
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9wNs.png

Comment: Create a static document with the divs and pull it in via ajax ? Unless you left out something in your code there is no real reason to create this dyncamically. Or create a single div and move the background one pixel a time to indicate seconds passing by.

Comment: You need to rethink your approach. Maybe some kind of drill down - first let the user to select hour and then show the rest of the information?

Comment: I am drawing a ruler of 1 Second, 5 Second & 10 Second respectively for 24 hour. So I need to draw so many divs at one go. Please refer to the above image posted in my question.

Comment: Even if we use ajax, we need to draw all divs. And browser gets crashed while drawing.  .. @EikePierstorff

Comment: User may select 24 Hour as he is free to chose, and in that case we need to draw all scales till 24 hours and so need to draw all divs.  @Esa

Comment: Actually I meant to create serverside a document with all your div and insert it in the page, not creating 86000 divs via ajax. The resulting DOM might still crash the browser, but your approach requires 86000 repaintings of the page and I doubt you can optimize for that.

Comment: I tried it by having static 86400 divs in a separate page and included it still it crashed. I think the real problem is browser is not able to render that many divs. @EikePierstorff

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do. How about making a parent div 86400px in length, which contains a child which grows 1px in length every second?

Comment: It's not about how much time it is taking to create div but the problem is browser is not able to render that many number of divs.@bluegman991

Comment: Have you considered using canvas instead?

Comment: canvas is having limitation that its size can't be greater than int size that is 32767 @forsvunnet

Comment: @user3110561 What about multiple canvas? Say one per hour?

Comment: I guess multiple canvas may also hamper the performance @forsvunnet but 'm trying and updates you

Answer (score 1):

one time append will increase the performance

```
var i;
var units = '';

for(i=0;i<86400;i++){
    units +='<div class="unit">'+i+'sec</div>';
}

$('#innerDiv').append(units);
```

But its worth to consider the techniques like this [techniques-smooth-infinite-scrolling-html5](http://engineering.linkedin.com/linkedin-ipad-5-techniques-smooth-infinite-scrolling-html5)  if you have these much no: of elements to display

Comment: It will? The HUGE string this will create will have to be kept in memory and parsed by jQuery in the end. Not to mention how much memory the string itself will consume...

Comment: Actually it might improve performance inasfar as the page needs to be redrawn only one time, plus of course you have a single method call instead if thousands of calls to append. You'd need to do a bit of benchmarking to see which solution does worse ( and I doubt it would make much difference either way).

Comment: The poor performance in the original code comes from writing to the DOM 86,400 times and parsing the albeit small chunk of HTML 86,400 times. The code here works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/P6NdK/ It writes to the DOM only once and only has the browser parse the HTML once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your end goal is but maybe you could scale out to showing only minutes or half hours depending on the scale of the number of hours. As a ruler a division of seconds seems excessive if a large timeframe of 24 hours is selected. I recently made a ruler using a table just to show the scale and that worked well. Are you interacting with all those divs via script after drawing them as this seems like a more likely reason for the crash especially if inserting static include crashes the browser as well which doesn't sound right. You might need to say what some of those post drawing tasks are, theres alwaysmore than one way to do things.

Anyway, if you know the width  the seconds will be you could create a background image with a 1 pixel left or right border and make it a repeating background on a larger div which represents a minute for instance (or the background image could be 5 minutes in a div of an hour). Each div could have a child element that displays the larger divs scale value (1, 2, 3 etc or 5, 10 15 etc as long as you have a scale key). The background image shows the seconds but you only create divs for the larger measurements of the scale with numbers. I can share some code if that might be a possble avenue for you.